# Папка, тека, фолдер, каталог, директорія в структурній ієрархії файлової системи

Tags: терміни, різниця-між-словами

Навряд чи варто орієнтуватись на СУМ у цьому випадку, адже з огляду на роки видання цей словник, ясна річ, не містить слово [**`фолдер`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/folder) взагалі, а значення слів [**`папка`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/papka), [**`тека`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/teka), [**`каталог`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/katalogh) і [**`директорія`**](http://sum.in.ua/s/dyrektorija) аж ніяк не пов'язані з комп'ютерною термінологією.

Вікіпедія теж не дає однозначної відповіді.

Статті за словами [**`папка`**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)), [**`тека`**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0) стверджують, що ці два слова, окрім того, що взаємозамінні, є ще й синонімами до **`директорії`** і **`каталогу`**.

Водночас, стаття у Вікіпедії на слово [**`директорія`**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F), як і в СУМ, не містить релевантних значень, а в статті на слово [**`каталог`**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)) все ж зазначаються певні нюанси:

> Власне кажучи, існує різниця в поняттях **`каталог`** і **`тека`**:
>   **`каталог`** — це елемент файлової системи та визначає список назв файлів, позаяк **`тека`** є метаформою контейнера в графічному
>   інтерфейсі. Наприклад, Microsoft Windows використовує концепцію
>   спеціальних тек для представлення користувачу елементів файлової
>   системи без занурення в абсолютні шляхи каталогів тощо.
>
> Для посилання на контейнер для документів більш прийнятним є термін
>   «**`тека`**». Але якщо йдеться про механізм, що відслідковує файли
>   документів, «**`каталог`**» буде найкращим вибором.

**Тож, чи зафіксована в якихось спеціалізованих джерелах усталена термінологія, що б чітко й однозначно визначала поняття складових ієрархії файлової системи?** Бажано, щоб було зрозуміло і не для фахівців, але це вже факультативно.

Comment: Наведена цитата з Вікіпедії правильно пояснює різницю між «directory» і «folder»: directory — це реальна, фізична директорія (об'єкт файлової системи, що має певну адресу, наприклад «C:\Users\Vasyl»), а folder — це те, що в графічному користувацькому інтерфейсі виглядає як відображення якогось directory (але не завжди ним є; folder може бути несправжнім, віртуальним, наприклад: folder «Принтери» в Microsoft Windows не є відображенням ніякого реального directory, а просто показує всі зареєстровані в системі принтери). Далі, НМД, folder=папка=тека, directory=директорія=каталог. Фолдер — є таке?

Comment: «Папка» і «тека» взагалі в укр. мові синоніми (за винятком специфічних значень типа «татко»), тому очевидно, що в цьому контексті вони обидва є аналогами англ. «folder». Російська вікіпедія непрямо каже, що російське «директория» в значенні «directory» — застаріла калька, а основне слово — «каталог»; ну, не знаю, чи це так і, зокрема, чи це так в українській. Про те, що в нас є літературне слово «фолдер» (а не як «я drop'нув ті spreadsheet'и у той folder»), я вперше чую, тому не знаю, яке значення в даному контексті воно може нести (якщо справді існує).

Comment: @Sasha, так і *папка*, і *тека*, і *каталог*, і *директорія* - всі запозичені. Так само може прижитися і *фолдер*, принаймні, як синонім.

Comment: Ну, мені особисто здається, що *в цьому контексті* це слово зайве (бо вже є аж *два* відповідники) — але от в російській мові це слово [вже вважається нормативним](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=фолдер), причому [в різних контекстах](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/фолдер#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) — тож, може, скоро і в нас буде (хоча при цьому може скластися так, що воно загалом літературне, але в цьому контексті не використовується).

Comment: За мовним порталом MicroSoft: [directory](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=directory&langID=uk-ua) = каталог,  [folder](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=folder&langID=uk-ua) = папка.

Comment: @Sasha, а як щодо оформлення відповіді, будь ласка!?

Comment: Чи я правильно розумію, у linux використовують зумисне не ті терміни, що у windows, але теж синоніми?

Comment: Папка є російським словом. Українське - тека. 
Тека (як і папка) завжди вкладена у каталог, каталог - об'єднання тек. 
Директорія - виключно комп'ютерний вислів (якщо в значенні місця зберігання документів). 
Стандартизації назв складових файлової системи не існує )

Answer (score 3):

Набагато точніше це питання описується на російській [Вікіпедії](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)), крім того там є посилання на джерела навідмінно від української версії. Згідно до поданої там інформації всі ці слова означають одне і те ж. Однак, слово "Директорія" вживалося раніше для позначення "елемента файлової системи, призначений для організації ієрархії файлової системи" і є транслітерацією англійського слова "directory".

Крім того:

> Термін **папка** (англ. **folder**) був введений для позначення
>   об'єктів файлової системи в графічному користувацькому інтерфейсі
>   шляхом аналогії з офісними папками. Він був вперше використаний в Mac
>   System Software, яка передувала Mac OS, а в системах Windows — з
>   виходом Windows 95. Ця метафора почала використовуватися в ОС Windows
>   NT, Mac OS, Mac OS X, а також системах UNIX.
>
> До виходу Windows 95 це поняття називалося словами **каталог або ж
>   директорія**, які є набагато влучнішими. Справа в тому, що слово папка
>   можна перекласти англійською як file, що може викликати додаткову
>   плутанину в головах некваліфікованих користувачів. Фізично існує
>   різновид канцелярської папки, на яку можна нанести слово "File", в
>   розмовній мові вона також називається "файл".

Тобто папка, фолдер, директорія та каталог - це синоніми, просто слова папка та фолдер є сучаснішими.

Comment: 1. Де саме, можна посилання? 2. Навіть в англійській слова _directory_ і _folder_ не є повними синонімами, тому навряд чи вони можуть буть повними синонімами в українській. 3. Російська термінологія й українська не забов'язані на 100% збігатися (а слова _тека_ в російській зовсім нема).

Comment: 1. @Sasha, Додав посилання, дякую, що помітили.
2. With the introduction of Windows 95, Microsoft started referring to directories as folders - https://www.codemag.com/Article/1307143/Murach%27s-C , на жаль, книгу 2005 року в ПДФі мені знайти не вдалося.

Comment: Щодо 2 — ок, зрозумів, виходить, деякі автори вважають ці слова синонімічними; однак (просто для інформації) зазначу, що [не всі](//devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=11473). За виправлення дякую.

Answer (score 2):

Наведена Вами цитата з Вікіпедії правильно пояснює різницю між *directory* і *folder*:

- **directory** — це реальна, фізична директорія (об'єкт файлової системи, що має певну адресу, наприклад `C:\Users\Vasyl`),
- а **folder** — це те, що в графічному користувацькому інтерфейсі виглядає як відображення якогось directory, але не завжди ним є. Folder може як відповідати реальному directory, так і бути «несправжнім», віртуальним, як-от folder «Принтери» в Microsoft Windows не є відображенням ніякого directory, а просто показує всі зареєстровані в системі принтери.

Звісно, для пересічного користувача ця різниця несуттєва. І навіть деякі спеціалісти не роблять різниці між цими термінами, використовуючи їх як практично синоніми. Однак деякі роблять. [Англійська Вікіпедія](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Directory_(computing)&oldid=879468838) наголошує цю різницю аналогічно до української: «there is a difference between a directory, which is a file system concept, and the graphical user interface metaphor that is used to represent it (a folder)» («є різниця між directory, що є поняттям [рівня] файлової системи, і метафорою [рівня] графічного користувацького інтерфейсу (folder)»). Аналогічно [робить Реймонд Чен](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=11473), пояснюючи, що не кожен folder є directory, а ті folder, які не є directory, називають virtual folder. (Щоправда у відповіді Реймонда Чена, по-моєму, бракує акцента, що folder — це не просто узагальнення для directory, а й погляд з іншої перспективи.) Тому фраза «всі ці слова означають одне і те ж» у [відповіді Анатолія](/a/5692) формально неправильна.

Далі по пунктах:

- **Папка** і **тека** взагалі в українській мові синоніми (за винятком, звісно, специфічних значень типа «татко», про які не говоримо), тому очевидно, що в цьому контексті вони обидва є відповідниками англійського **folder**.
- **Директорія** і **каталог** — відповідники до **directory**.

  «Словник української мови» у 20 томах має слово *[директо́рія](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=177331&page=760)* з потрібним значенням («інформ[атика]. Вузол, який містить інформацію про файли») і слово *[катало́г](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40909&page=1292)* без потрібного значення. Утім це необов'язково означає, що такого значення немає, його могли просто забути додати. «Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови», навпаки, містить слово *[директо́рія](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)* без потрібного значення і слово ''[каталог](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3)'' зі значенням, що приблизно нагадує потрібне.

  [Російська Вікіпедія](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)&oldid=93746250), можливо, натякає, що російське *директория* в цьому значенні застаріло («ранее часто использовалось слово *директо́рия*, которое представляет собой транслитерацию с английского» («раніше часто використовували слово *директо́рія*, що є транслітерацією з англійської»)). Хоча, можливо, вони й не мали цього на увазі (з того, що слово використовували «ранее» («раніше»), формально не випливає, що нині його не використовують). У будь-якому разі, українська — не російська і з того, що слово застаріло в російській, не випливає, що воно застаріло в українській, тим паче, що навіть [російські словники](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F) містять *директория* без поміток про застарілість.
- Про те, що в українській мові може бути літературне слово **фолдер**, я чую вперше. Відповідно, я про це слово нічого не знаю.